# Browser hangs when accessing /delcookie route?

Tags: node.js, cookies, express

I am able to set and print the cookie object but when I access the `delcookie` route, my browser hangs and does not delete the cookie.

Is my syntax correct for the delcookie route?

```
var express = require ("express");
var app = express();

app.use( express.cookieParser() );

app.get('/setcookie', function(req, res){
  res.cookie('cookiename', 'cookievalue', { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
  res.send ('200', "<div style='font-weight:bold; color:blue'>setting cookie</div>");
  console.log (req.cookies);
});

app.get('/printcookie', function(req, res){
  res.send ('200', "<div style='font-weight:bold;'>printing cookie</div>");
  console.log (req.cookies);
});

app.get('/delcookie', function(req, res){
  res.clearCookie('cookiename', { path: '/setcookie' });
});

app.listen(1337);
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually sending a response.  The `sendCookie` method tells Express to add a header that will delete the cookie *when the response is sent*.

Add something that does send a response:

```
app.get('/delcookie', function(req, res){
  res.clearCookie('cookiename', { path: '/setcookie' });
  res.send('ok');
});
```