# Why does my app appear to be listening on port 3501 but my browser can not connect to localhost on that port?

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

I am doing this [PERN tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J01rYl9T3BU&t=5119s) on youtube and I have run into the following problem. Although my terminal shows the expected output I can not access the port via localhost on my browser. Have tried firefox and chrome. Here is the code:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/getRestaurants", (req, resp) => {
  console.log("get all restaurants");
});

//http://localhost:3501/getRestaurants

const port = process.env.PORT || 3500;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server is up and listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

And the output in the command line is:

```
server is up and listening on port 3501
get all restaurants
```

But when I try to navigate to http://localhost:3501/getRestaurants, It loads forever. The output from ss -tlwn shows it listening too:

```
 - Netid: tcp
 - State: LISTEN
 - Recv-Q: 0
 - Send-Q: 511
 - Local Address: Port:*:3501
 - Peer Address:Port: *:*
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Browser hangs when accessing /delcookie route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669647/browser-hangs-when-accessing-delcookie-route)

Comment: Yes I would expect that as /getRestaurants currently doesn't return a response.  Watch the next minute of the video where he adds a response.

Comment: Try something like `resp.send("Hello")` inside your /getRestaurants route

Comment: "It loads forever" — For future debugging reference, if it sits there forever then that's a decent sign that it has made a connection and just hasn't got what it wanted back. If it couldn't connect then it would rapidly fail with an error screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to connect to your server from your browser, in order to load the page, your browser should get a response. Since you're not returning any data from server to request, your browser waits and most likely time-outs after some time.

Try this.

```
app.get("/getRestaurants", (req, resp) => {
    console.log("get all restaurants");
    resp.send("get all restaurants");
});
```